# Correct use of malloc and strcat to avoid memory errors with valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have stored vertices in my tempStorage :

```
typedef struct {
    int pred[8];
    int succ[8];
} arc_set;

arc_set tempStorage;
```

for example .pred are 0,1,1,2,2 and .succ are 2,2,3,3,1

I have made a `char *links = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);` to store these numbers and print them like this:

```
            char *temp = malloc(10);

            for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++){

                    sprintf(temp, "%d-%d ", tempStorage.pred[l], tempStorage.succ[l]);
                    strcat(links, temp);

            }
            free(temp);

            fprintf(stdout, "Solution %d edges: %s",countLinks, links);
            fprintf(stdout, "\n");
```

storing strings in format "%d-%d " in temp with `sprintf` and then with `strcat` concat that with links.

it does print everything correctly but when I test it with `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes -v ./programname` I do get:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12322==    at 0x4C2C66A: strcat (vg_replace_strmem.c:307)
==12322==    by 0x4013CC: main (program.c:251)
==12322==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==12322==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==12322==    by 0x401270: main (program.c:225)
```

where c:251 is `strcat(links, temp);` and c:225 is my `char *links = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);`

am I using strcat wrong or what is the problem here?

Comment: Adding to the answers/comments, besides ensuring the first octet of `links[]` is zero before embarking on your for-loop, the dynamic management of `temp` is pointless. `char temp[10];` would be sufficient. And seriously consider whether this is really a solid solution. Ex: Why 100? Because 99 isn't quite enough and 101 is just too much? If the cap is a genuine unknown your code should be prepared for that, not assume and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory you've got from `malloc` isn't zero-initialized by default. And `strcat` will append the new to the end of the string. For non-zero-initialized chunk of memory that could be just anywhere.

You don't need to set the whole `links` to zero -- just first byte would be enough. Still `memset(links, 0, 100);` right after `malloc` would not hurt.

Comment: How about using `calloc` instead?